# MQSeries 5.0 - compression and message integrity

Tags: ibm-mq

I have to connect Webshpere MQ 7.1 with MQSeries 5.0. I have to choose between message compression on application level or turn on the compression in MQ natively. I cannot, however, connect to MQSeries 5.0 and check whether or not it support things I care about - compression and message integrity.

Therefore, my question is this:
Does MQSeries 5.0 (in that particular version) provide message compression and/or ensures the message integrity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer - no.

Longer answer, you can verify this because the old WMQ manuals are still online [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/library/).  I checked the V5.3 Intercommunications Manual and the MQSC Script Reference manual and the only mention of compression was that you might want to write use of channel exits to perform that function.

If you did write a channel exit, it would not interoperate with WMQ V7.1 since the channel negotiation would disable that feature on the WMQ V7.1 side.  It would be necessary to install the exit on both sides.

With all levels of MQ V5 many years out of support, skip the effort to alter the application or write an exit and just migrate to a current, supported version of MQ.

Comment: And what about message integrity? Should I implement some checksum control on both ends?

Comment: Depends on which V5.x you have.  V5.3 introduced SSL so you could use that for an integrity check. V5.3 doesn't use TLS and the SSL protocol itself is broken so you won't actually get security or very good integrity checking. Again, the advice is to just get a modern version of WMQ, in this case so you can use TLS.